# how to display textview below button in relativeLayout

Tags: android, button, textview, android-relativelayout

in the below xml layout, i have two buttons at the same position and they will do their function based on the visibilty set. now i tried to place two textviews 
below the buttons, i want the text views to be below both buttons so I used

```
android:layout_below="@id/actConnect2_btn_connect"
```

but at run time when the connect-button is visible the text view appears below it, and if pair-button is visible it overlap

how to display the textview below both buttons?

Note: i know that i can use android:layout:marginTop but i want to solve it without it

**code**:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/actConnect2_btn_pair"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/actConnect2_tv_label_devClass"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/str_pair"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/actConnect2_btn_connect"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/str_connect"
    android:layout_below="@+id/actConnect2_tv_label_devClass"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actConnect2_tv_label_uuids"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/actConnect2_btn_connect"
    android:text="Service's UUID: ">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actConnect2_tv_uuids"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/actConnect2_tv_label_uuids">
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take both button in one layout

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/actConnect2_tv_label_devClass"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
     android:id="@+id/actConnect2_btn_pair"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:text="@string/str_pair"/>

<Button
     android:id="@+id/actConnect2_btn_connect"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/str_connect"

    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and use this for your textview

```
android:layout_below="@id/relativeButton"
```

Answer (score 6):

Put both buttons in a LinearLayout then put the textview below the LinearLayout

Answer (score 2):

You have to place the buttons in a Layout (any type and arrange them accordingly)
Assign an ID to that layout.
Place the textView below that layout ID.